# create user-movie rating array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

i am using a database found on the internet about user and their movies ratings. after i read them from a csv file and save them to a data frame i want to create an array of user-movie ratings.

```
user_dataframe : user_id,movie_id,stars
                    0       02      3
                    1       01      2
                    2       03      5
                    0       01      4
                    0       03      5

movie_dataframe : movie_id,average_rating,genre
                     02        3.5        horror
                     03         4         action
                     01        2.5        adventure
```

expected output of the array :

```
user_id |  0  |  1   | 2  
movie_id|     |      |
01      |  4  |  2   | NaN
02      |  3  | NaN  | NaN
03      |  5  | NaN  |  5
```

i tried using df.pivot_table but i get an error that says : contains duplicate entries , cannot reshape. Also i tried with numpy arrays but i had trouble using it with strings. Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

i tried with

```
df.pivot_table(index='movie_id',columns='user_id')
```

and it works

Comment: this didnt work for me because i have got too many values and when i execute this command i get error message `IndexError: index 815938881 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 815934795`